# How to create custom column filter for primeng table in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

Is it possible to create custom filter for one of my column in data table ? in the column are Wind directions for specific day each hour (for eg  245° SW), i setup multiselect column filter with options (North, East, West...etc) so when user select North in the filter it filters data which contains N , i have no idea how can i implement this any help please ? https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/table/filter this is the filter i used (its for the Agent row in the table)

this is my html

```
....code
<th pSortableColumn="direction">Wind Direction <p-sortIcon field="direction"></p-sortIcon>
            <p-columnFilter field="direction" matchMode="in" display="menu" [showMatchModes]="false" [showOperator]="false" [showAddButton]="false">
              <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
                  <p-multiSelect [ngModel]="value" [options]="windDirections" placeholder="Any" (onChange)="filter($event.value)" optionLabel="direction">
                      <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
                          <div class="p-multiselect-wind-option">
                            <span class="pi pi-compass mr-5px"></span>
                            <span style="margin-left: 5px;">{{option.direction}}</span>
                          </div>
                      </ng-template>
                  </p-multiSelect>
              </ng-template>
          </p-columnFilter></th>
...
...code
```

this is ts where i setup my directions

```
 this.windDirections = [
      { direction: 'North', code: 'N' },
      { direction: 'North East', code: 'NE' },
      { direction: 'North West', code: 'NW' },
      { direction: 'South', code: 'S' },
      { direction: 'South West', code: 'SW' },
      { direction: 'South East', code: 'SE' },
      { direction: 'East', code: 'E' },
      { direction: 'West', code: 'W' },
    ];
```

this is how the the data i am trying to filter look like ["256° SW","244° SW","202° S","245° SW" ... etc]

```
....
...code
weatherDataWithLoader$.subscribe({
      next: (historicalWeatherData) => {
        const temperatures = historicalWeatherData.hourly.temperature_2m;
        const times = historicalWeatherData.hourly.time.map((time) =>
          this.datePipe.transform(time, 'shortTime')
        );
        const humidities = historicalWeatherData.hourly.relativehumidity_2m;
        const windSpeeds = historicalWeatherData.hourly.windspeed_10m;
        const airPressures = historicalWeatherData.hourly.surface_pressure;
        const windDirections =
          historicalWeatherData.hourly.winddirection_10m.map((item) =>  // here i added 'N','S','W' etc based on direction
            this.checkWindDirection(item)
          );
        const precipitations = historicalWeatherData.hourly.precipitation;
        const rain = historicalWeatherData.hourly.rain;
        const cloudcover = historicalWeatherData.hourly.cloudcover;
        const soilTemperatures =
          historicalWeatherData.hourly.soil_temperature_0_to_7cm;

        temperatures.forEach((value, i) => {
          this.weatherData.push(
            new WeatherDataItem(
              value,
              times[i],
              humidities[i],
              windSpeeds[i],
              airPressures[i],
              windDirections[i],
              precipitations[i],
              rain[i],
              cloudcover[i],
              soilTemperatures[i]
            )
          );
        });
      },
...
...code
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what your problem is? What's the behavior? Your filter show up but doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, when i selected any of the choice in the multiselect filter it doesnt work like all my data from table dissapear like in no data is matching the selection (when i select North for eg only the data with N should stay in the table)

Comment: You could check the [filterService](https://primefaces.org/primeng/filterservice) of primeNg to enable it, I never found the proper documentation and usually just define a filter() method to filter the data on my end

Comment: Do you have example by any chance on filter which is filtering column with contains

Comment: Not using the primeNg filter I'm afraid. I think your easiest solution is to construct a proper object with the wind direction in your  "checkWindDirection" method, or filter the list by yourself (hard to concile with other primeNg filters)